# How to send data via HTTP to Pub/Sub from a microcontroller that has no GCP SDK?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm new to GCP and want to practice building data pipelines. To get it start, I want a source that can send regular data to GCP. I have a microcontroller with an internet connection that monitors temperature. I want to send the temperature data every minute directly to Pub/Sub via REST.

All documentation I can find seems to assume that the device that is going to send the data is able to download GCP SDKs. This is not true for microcontrollers that have no OS. Google has just killed off IoT Core, and I can't find any GCP native methods that support microcontrollers for this purpose.

Is there a barebones way to send data to GCP over an HTTP PUT if the sender is a device that has no SDKs or libraries, or does GCP not support this?

Comment: Pub/Sub has a REST API. You do not need to use an SDK, but it will make development easier. Review the various posts about Pub/Sub on Stack Overflow. You will find a lot of code examples. I have posted answers showing how to create access tokens and call REST APIs in Python without using an SDK. Research first and then post a question.

Comment: I'm aware that Pub/Sub has a REST API. My question is about using that REST API on a microcontroller that doesn't have access to any SDKs or libraries. I've been searching for a couple days with no solution. I have yet to find one of the "lot of" code examples showing how to do this, nor do I see an explanation in any of your answers.

Comment: This [one](https://www.jhanley.com/blog/google-cloud-creating-oauth-access-tokens-for-rest-api-calls/) might help.

Comment: Use the keywords in my article to search. We have a [GDE](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11372593/guillaume-blaquiere) that has also written many answers on Stack Overflow and on [medium](https://guillaume-blaquiere.medium.com/).